# AngularJS dynamically load template and js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to dynamically add menu JavaScript file and html to content.html, but it can't do.

I created simple example

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TfBfInLUJzIhYP3yRqkr)

I try move  "`<script src="menu.js"></script>`" to menu.html

Comment: did you even load angularjs library?

Comment: sure,it's part code.

Comment: It'd be good if you create a fiddle to show the problem.

Comment: You got to use router for that. You can either use ngRoute or uiRoute. I prefer uiRoute.

Answer (score 1):

Your code moves away from the whole idea of writing single page app with angular. I have updated it to give you basic idea of how you would do the routes and share templates and use controller.

Check out the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rZYx2LNL6HTFIyXZ6DcJ?p=preview)

**html**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/805e69bae319e922e4d3265b7ef565058aaff850/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="menu" ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**js**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});

angular.module('app',['moduleContent', 'moduleMenu', 'ui.router']);

var app = angular.module('app');

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: "first.html",
      controller: 'firstCtrl'
    })
    .state('second', {
      url: "/second",
      templateUrl: "second.html"
    })
});

app.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.page = "first";
}]);

//Conttent module
angular.module('moduleContent',[])
.controller('contentCtrl', contentCtrl);

function contentCtrl(shareData)
{
    shareData.currentPage = 0;
}
```

Comment: why I can't use multi page?

Comment: Why do you want to use multi page?

Comment: and template page own js css file belong itself